# <h:link> disabled attribute not evaluating properly

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0

I have an `@Stateful` EJB in a `@SessionScoped` bean.

My EJB:

```
@Stateful
public class SomeEjb implements someEjbInterface{
    private SomeEntity entity;

    @Override
    public Boolean getEntityAssigned(){
        return entity!= null;
    }

    @Override
    public void selectEntity(String id){
        //assign entity with some values retrieved from db according to the criteria
    }
}
```

My Session Scoped Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean{
    @EJB
    private SomeEntity entity;

    //getter and setter

    public String selectEntity(){
        entity.selectEntity(someId);
        return null;
        //Edited: if using this, no problem will occur.
        // return "index";
    }
}
```

My Page index.xhtml (xmlns omitted):

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Select entity" action="#{sessionBean.selectEntity()}">
</h:form>
<h:link outcome="someOutcome" disabled="#{sessionBean.entity.entityAssigned}">
```

I expect that the link is initially disabled, when I click "Select entity", the ejb will retrieve an entity from database, if the retrieve succeed, then the link will be enabled.

The problem is that when I click the button, the link will break (rendering an  tag with href attribute but no innerHtml to click). It can only be fixed if I reload the page without data resubmission(re-enter the page by pressing enter at the url, not using F5 which will resubmit the form).

The error message is:

```
HTML nesting warning on closing span: element a rendered by component : {Component-Path : some long component path refer to the link element} not explicitly closed
```

Does anyone know what did I messed up with the rendering?

Edit:

I just found out that the problem does not exist if I return the outcome of that same page instead of null, which probably discard `@ViewScoped` bean I used to call `sessionBean.selectEntity()`. Can anyone explain the mechanism for the cause of this difference?

Comment: Your design is very strange. An EJB is not intented to be used as a model/entity, but as a business service. You should absolutely not have the need to reference the EJB from the view side on.

Comment: @BalusC I tried to retrieve the entity in the SFSB so I can later operate on it by calling other methods predefined in the SFSB to edit the entity in some allowed way. But then I need to store the handle to a session bean in order to be able to get back the SFSB throughout the session, and I try to enable the link only if the entity had been retrieved.

Comment: I believe you completely missed the real meaning of `@Stateful`. This must be interpreted in context of DB transactions, not in context of Java instances or so.

Comment: @BalusC As I think it might not be relevant to include more information here, I've created a new question describing the whole situation I am working with. Please kindly have a look and comment on the design adopted. [Correct Usage of Stateful Session Bean in EJB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721261/correct-usage-of-stateful-session-bean-in-ejb)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) says that the "toString" of the object returned by the method will be used to handel navigation, you can try returning "" (no navigation, only refresh the page).

Please add the relevant parts of the xhtml.